# Setting a cookie from one url and getting from another, why it doesn't work if path is not set to '\'?

Tags: java, javascript, cookies

I was trying to implement this: http://geekswithblogs.net/GruffCode/archive/2010/10/28/detecting-the-file-download-dialog-in-the-browser.aspx

The problem is, I have a page with url: `localhost/portal/myapp`, dynamically, on that page I generate a form with `action` attribute equals to `localhost/servlet/myapp/generatexls`, so I'm setting a cookie in a servlet that handles that url. The thing is, I later try to read my cookie from javascript in my original page on `localhost/portal/myapp`, but I can't. If while setting cookie a path equals to `/`, then happily I can read it. So, the question is, why without setting a path to `/` my cookie can't be read on original url, and why it matters and what's wrong with cookie if path isn't set to `/`, does it implicitly set to form's action parameter? (`/servlet/myapp/generatexls`) and that's why I can't read it?

Comment: What is your question? And in which response do you see a cookie that is afterwards not available?

Comment: I see a cookie in http response. It's not that it's unavailable, it simply isn't saved in document. That response, it contains file that user requests.

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't saved"? Your code calls `eraseCookie()`, is that not what is expected?

Comment: I mean, that in response I see "Set-cookie" header, but cookie itself doesn't get saved. Regarding 'eraseCookie()', it doesn't go to that stage, it simply cannot find token, i.e. cookie. I can remove that `eraseCookie`, it doesn't matter. I still cannot find my cookie.

Comment: Can you show us the Java code creating the response?

Comment: What's `response` and `p_response`?

Comment: it's HttpServletResponse

Comment: @Bergi please reopen this question, I've amended it.

Comment: I could vote to reopen it, but that hardly will happen. Please revert your edit and ask it as a different question (with different title), then it's likelier to be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do buff.writeTo the output stream last!

The header settings only work when still nothing is written to the response. As headers are written first.

Questionable: file.close() missing, does all get written. outStream.close() maybe better not done. Maybe cookie.setPath("/")

Nicer would be if there was a file.length() for setting the content length header, and do file.writeTo the response output stream.

Comment: At first, let me thank you very much for your answer. And to say mosrt important things first, setting path helped and it doesn't matter whether I add cookie before `buff.writeTo(outStream); outStream.close();` or after, it works anyway.

Comment: So despite your answer really helped me to solve my problem, I want to find out, why do I need to set path. I've amended question text to better describe this.

Comment: That it worked in reverse order is a matter of buffering, on which I would not rely for large files (to my knowledge). Try it out. Cookies can be set for directories, say /psychology, /chemistry or root /. Depending on the URL http://.../chemistry/, you'll see only cookies for /chemistry and /.

Comment: So, regarding header settings position, you're saying that it worked for me, when I placed `addCookie()` after `outstream.close()` because my file wasn't written to a response yet, because of buffering, is this correct? Or there are some  buffering mechanisms, that preclude response to understand that all info was written and thus it allows to add a cookie?

Comment: Regarding cookie paths, I probably found in RFC:6265 an answer to my question, it says: " When the user agent "receives a cookie" from a request-uri with, the user agent MUST process the cookie as follows: 7. If the cookie-attribute-list contains an attribute with an attribute-name of "Path", set the cookie's path to attribute-value.  Otherwise, set the cookie's path to the default-path of the request-uri."

Comment: Correct: there is one output with header lines, empty line and file contents, say HTML or PDF.

Comment: continuation of my previous comment: I'm not sure what default path of request-uri is, but probably it's somehow related to request-uri in and my case request-uri path is `servlet/myapp/generatexls`, so I think that is what cookie path set to by browser. And it looks like chrome doesn't allow access to cookie that has path different from current path.

Comment: Regarding response output, could you please provide me some spec or documentation on it behavior regarding writing data, order, etc?

Comment: In general one can let display the cookies in the browser. Response output: Header lines, empty line, then content; that's all for the **HTTP protocol**.